# SVG animation properly not closing at the end(small Gap persists)

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm relatively new to SVG. Trying to implement hexagon loader, 90% has been completed but at the end of the animation hexagon not closing completely(a small gap persists). Actually i used Adobe Illustrator for getting path coordinates.

Link: jsfiddle.net/srigar/fhmbqtg7/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several approaches you can take.  If you don't mind rounded joins, then you can take @demonofthemists's approach.

But before I demonstrate other approaches, I am going to clean up your path.  It uses 15 path commands to make a hexagon. You should only need 6. Also it has a stray "-0" at the end that does nothing.  I also cleaned up the CSS.  Finally, your path is only 245.68 in length, so a dash array of 300 is too long and, as a consequence, you are not seeing the effect of your `ease-in-out` animation timing.

Here's the cleaned up sample.

```css
.loader path {
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: none;
}

.loader #fill {
  stroke:#4C83C4;
  stroke-dasharray: 246;
  animation: dash 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.loader #border {
  stroke:#d6d5d5;
}
.loader svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 246;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 97.59 119.306">
    <g>
      <path id="border"
            d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"/>
      <path id="fill"
            d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<label>Author: SRIGAR</label>
```

Okay, to solutions.

**1. "square"line caps and mask**

You could switch to square line caps instead of round, but that will result in the caps extending outside of the hexagon shape. You could fix that by using a mask.

```css
.loader path {
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: none;
}

.loader #fill {
  stroke:#4C83C4;
  stroke-dasharray: 246;
  stroke-linecap: square;
  animation: dash 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  mask: url(#loader-mask);
}
.loader #border {
  stroke:#d6d5d5;
}
.loader svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 246;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 97.59 119.306">
    <defs>
      <mask id="loader-mask">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
        <path d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"
              stroke="white"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <path id="border"
            d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"/>
      <path id="fill"
            d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<label>Author: SRIGAR</label>
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't look good at the start of the path.

**2. Extend end of path, with mask**

Another approach would be to eschew the line caps, and instead just extend the end of the path past the start point a bit.  Of course, that makes the line longer, so you need to make the dash array value bigger also.  And we still need to use the mask, so that we only see the parts of the line extension that we want to keep.

```css
.loader path {
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: none;
}

.loader #fill {
  stroke:#4C83C4;
  stroke-dasharray: 250;
  animation: dash 5s ease-in-out infinite;
  mask: url(#loader-mask);
}
.loader #border {
  stroke:#d6d5d5;
}
.loader svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 250;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 97.59 119.306">
    <defs>
      <mask id="loader-mask">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
        <path d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"
              stroke="white"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <path id="border"
            d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"/>
      <path id="fill"
            d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 l-38.8,-22.6"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<label>Author: SRIGAR</label>
```

So there are a couple of techniques to get you started.  You could get fancier if you want - for example if you wanted a vertical start/end join, then you could do that using a couple of masks and splitting the animation into two parts.  But I'll leave things simple for now, to avoid making this answer too confusing.

**Update**

**3. A neater start and end**

```css
.loader path {
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: none;
}

.loader #fill-left,
.loader #fill-right {
  stroke:#4C83C4;
  animation: dash 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.loader #fill-left {
  stroke-dasharray: 254;
  mask: url(#left-mask);
}

.loader #fill-right {
  stroke-dasharray: 168 254;
  mask: url(#right-mask);
}

.loader #border {
  stroke:#d6d5d5;
}
.loader svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 254;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 97.59 119.306">
    <defs>
      <mask id="left-mask">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
        <path d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"
              stroke="white"/>
        <rect x="43.3" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
      </mask>
      <mask id="right-mask">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
        <path d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"
              stroke="white"/>
        <rect width="43.3" height="100%" fill="black"/>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <g>
      <path id="border"
            d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"/>
      <path id="fill-left"
            d="M46.8,6 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 l-38.8,-22.6"/>
      <path id="fill-right"
            d="M8,69.8 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 l-38.8,-22.6"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>

<label>Author: SRIGAR</label>
```

How it works.

As mentioned above, in order to get the neater start and end, we have to split the mask into two halves.  One is for the left half so that we can extend the start line (like we did for the end line) and make the start point vertical. The second is so that we can extend the end line like we did earlier.

For clarity, here is what the left mask looks like.

```css
.loader path {
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: none;
}

.loader svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 97.59 119.306">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
    <path d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"
          stroke="white"/>
    <rect x="43.3" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And here is the right mask.

```css
.loader path {
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: none;
}

.loader svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 97.59 119.306">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
    <path d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"
          stroke="white"/>
    <rect width="43.3" height="100%" fill="black"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

If we remove the masking and make the fill lines translucent, you can see how they are arranged to work with the masks.

```css
.loader path {
  stroke-width: 10;
  fill: none;
  stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}

.loader #fill-left,
.loader #fill-right {
  stroke:#4C83C4;
  animation: dash 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.loader #fill-left {
  stroke-dasharray: 254;
}

.loader #fill-right {
  stroke: red;
  stroke-dasharray: 168 254;
}

.loader #border {
  stroke:#d6d5d5;
}
.loader svg {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 254;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg viewBox="0 -10 97.59 119.306">
    <g>
      <path id="border"
            d="M43.3,8.1 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 z"/>
      <path id="fill-left"
            d="M46.8,6 L8,28.6 v41.2 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 l-38.8,-22.6"/>
      <path id="fill-right"
            d="M8,69.8 L43.3,90.3 L78.6,69.8 V28.6 l-38.8,-22.6"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Its really helpful. But the starting point doesn't look good, like unfinished, is this possible to start from bottom(left to right).

Comment: You would get the same problem if you just started from one of the other corners.  It would not be a "neat" start.  You could start from the middle of one side if you redrew the hexagon, but if you did that you wouldn't have the problem that this question was all about. So I assume you wouldn't want to do that.

Comment: If you wanted a "neat" start - eg the start was vertical across the start joint, then that is possible, but you need to get a bit more tricky. You would need more than one mask (one for the start of the animatioon, and one for the end). As per the final paragraph in my answer.

Comment: I've added an example of how to get a neater start and end.

Comment: can u please help me out to rotate this in a clockwise direction. `jsfiddle.net/srigar/fhmbqtg7/5/`

Comment: Rotate what in a clockwise direction?  By how many degrees?  Rotating elements in SVG is very simple. I think it is something you could work out yourself perhaps.

Comment: Currently it start animating from right side to left side but i just want to start animate from left side to right side. Example: loadergenerator.com/arrow

Comment: I don't understand. My example *does* animated from the left side to the right side.

Comment: Literally the best answer in all stackoverlflow

Answer (score 2):

Just add `stroke-linecap:round;` to your blue path.

To avoid mismatch is sharp & round edges add, `stroke-linejoin: round;` to both the paths

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhmbqtg7/4/)

Comment: Yeah its good. But i can able to see a very small gap at the top corner. Becoz background one was sharp corner but now we used round cap property. Is thr any other soln?.

Comment: @Srigar If you can round the sharp edges, I've updated answer, use stroke-linejoin

Comment: It make sense.. Thanks..!